# C++ display a vector of pairs by using copy

Tags: c++, vector, printing, copy, std-pair

```
std::vector<std::pair<Pos, int>> v;
// sort and other stuff...
std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<std::pair<Pos, int>>> out_it(std::cout, "\n");
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), out_it); // error
```

Currently studying STL and trying to print to console by using `copy`. I have an `operator<<` for displaying pairs, should I make one for displaying vector? Or is there another way? `Pos` is just a class I defined, it has a private member string.

Comment: C++ does not automatically figure out how to take an arbitrary class and convert it to a string representation that can be dumped to `std::cout`. You have to write explicit code to do it. Note that this goes for `std::pair` too, in addition to your own class.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You mean I will need to make an overload of `operator<<` for displaying `std::vector`? I do have an overload of `operator<<` for displaying `std::pair`

Comment: why ostream_iterator's Type parameter is vector, not type of member of vector? Are you to store multiple vectors to ostream? and yeah, you need define behavior  for the  type you want to serialize

Comment: Yes. There are no predefined overloads of `<<` for vectors.

Comment: @Swift So you mean `std::ostream_iterator<v> out_it(std::cout, "\n");` instead?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, I've made an `operator<<` overload for displaying vector, but compilers give me this error `error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<std::pair<Pos, int> > >' and 'std::pair<Pos, int>')|`

Comment: @user3221454 That error caused by copy's code, std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), out_it) iterates _through_ vector. It tries to copy pairs where you instructed it to expect vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <vector>
#include  <iterator>

namespace std {
template <class T1, class T2>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::pair< T1, T2>& rhs)
    {
      out << "first: " << rhs.first << " second: " << rhs.second;
      return out;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::pair< size_t, int > pp(1,2);
    std::vector<std::pair< size_t, int >> v;
    v.push_back(pp);
    v.push_back(pp);
    v.push_back(pp);

    std::ostream_iterator<std::pair< size_t, int >> out_it(std::cout, "\n");
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), out_it); 
}
```

std::copy() iterates from value given by first parameter to second, using third parameter as iterator for destination. Types should match, obviously.

If you define iterator for stream of vectors you do not need std::copy to  output single vector ( that should be code for  operator<< ?)